# Why does fstream.open() fail "If the mode has both trunc and app set"?

Tags: c++, io, fstream

It took me quite a while to figure out that my `.open()` call wasn't opening a file because I had both the `trunc` and `app` mode options set. I only figured this out after catching a little note written on the [C++ docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/).

This seems like a weird gotcha. Why is this the case? Can you not truncate the file and then append only? Or is this considered superfluous specification?

Comment: How can you discard existing file content and keep it at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iostream` open modes correspond roughly to the [`fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) mode in the C library and `fopen` has a `w` mode that truncates and an `a` mode that appends, but no combination of the two.

Comment: C++ IOStreams aren't mandated to use the C I/O library internally, so why should this matter?

Comment: `basic_filebuf::open` **is** mandated to behave "as if by calling `std::fopen(s,modstr)`" even if it doesn't actually use it internally. See [filebuf.members]/2

Answer (score 4):

The allowable combinations of flags are specified in [filebuf.members] in the standard. Table 132 gives the possibilities:

[image]

So, since the combination of `trunc` and `app` isn't in the table, the open is required to fail.